# Strange interaction of apply with collapse argument to paste

Tags: r

Wanted to get some clarification on some unintended output I got trying to `apply` the `paste` function with the `collapse` argument across a data frame. I can't find anything in the documentation to explicitly suggest this should happen, though I might be missing something.

Reproducible example:

```
data <- data.frame(a = 8:11, b = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

apply(data, 1, paste, collapse = ' ')
```

Desired output:

```
'8 a', '9 b', '10 c', '11 d'
```

Actual output:

```
' 8 a', ' 9 b', '10 c', '11 d'
```

It seems that in this case R is padding out the digits of the numbered vectors with empty space. This does not happen if you try the same `paste` call outside of `apply`:

```
paste(data[1, ], collapse = ' ')
```

Result:

```
'8 a'
```

Comment: Interesting behaviour indeed. My guess  it has something to do with coercing to a matrix, but I couldn't manually reproduce this. You could alternatively do `do.call(paste, data)` though for both speed and desired output

Comment: Very nice, `do.call` solves my issue for now. I am still curious as to what causes this behaviour though. You got the expected output when running my input?

Comment: No, I could reproduce this behaviour, but not sure what causing it. As I said, I'm guessing it has something to do with coercion to a matrix within `apply`. As a side note, I almost never use `apply` for anything when dealing with `data.frame`s, there is almost always another way. `apply` is mainly useful for matrices.

Comment: I did reproduce it. Also, changing last *a* value to 100 increases padding in all previous elements.

Comment: No padding of one digit numbers in "a", if pasted with a one digit number instead of a letter: `data <- data.frame(a = 8:11, b = 8, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`; `apply(data, 1, paste, collapse = ' ')`. Hmm.

Comment: It seems that `apply` calls `as.matrix.data.frame` which calls `format` if any column is not "numeric"; e.g. `format(8:11)`

Comment: I'd be happy to accept that as an answer if you'd like to post it alexis_laz!